# Sending String from Android to PHP Server via POST

Tags: java, php, android

In an Android app I am creating I am attempting to send a username in the form of a string to my PHP web server. My code compiles without error, and I know the variable I'm passing to the function isn't null (toasted the variable and the value is what I want). However, when I try to get the string by using a POST request, the string I want is null. How can I retrieve the string?

On A side note, I am new to Android and I'm not sure as to weather or not I should be putting this in a class that extends AsyncTask. I had to do that in another function that I used to retrieve data from the web server. Here is my code:

```
public void sendInfo(String url, String user, String pass){
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    try{
        // Add the data
        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post request
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the PHP code I am using to retrieve the post:

```
// ...... Code to connect to database works fine

$new_username = $_POST['username'];

if(is_null($new_username)){
    echo 'string is null';
}

echo $new_username;
```

When I view the web page, I only see the text "string is null"

Answer (score 0):

Per the [HttpClient - Post Method](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/post.html) documentation, you should probably be using something like

```
PostMethod post = new PostMethod(url);
NameValuePair[] data = {
      new NameValuePair("username", user),
      new NameValuePair("password", password)
};
post.setRequestBody(data);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.execute(post);
InputStream in = post.getResponseBodyAsStream();
// handle response...
```

Comment: How do I handle the response? I am still getting null when trying to get the _POST in my PHP

Comment: Is `user` null in your request? Are you sure? What does the apache log say?

Answer (score 0):

I had create a subclass of AsyncTask to run the function